# Square root of Sequence approaches square root value.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $x$ is a real number, and $x_n\geq 0$, and $x_n→x$ as n grows. Prove that $\sqrt {x_n}→\sqrt x$ as $n$ grows.

Attempt: Case 1: $x = 0$. 
Suppose that $x$ is a real number, and $x_n \geq 0$. Let $\epsilon >$ 0. Then for every epsilon, there a natural number $N$ such that $|x_n| < \epsilon$.

Please any help? Can anyone please help me with this proof?
Thank you.

Comment: The crux of the proof is that when $|x_n-x|$ is bounded, so is $|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt x|$. Find a relation between the two expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to solve such questions,
it is often useful to explicitly state what you have to do and what you know.
In doing so,
how to turn what you know into what you want sometimes becomes a bit clearer.

**What you have to prove:** You must prove that $\sqrt{x_n}$ converges to $\sqrt{x}$,
or,
in rigorous terms,
that for any $\epsilon>0$,
there exists a certain index $N\in\mathbb N$ such that if $n\geq N$ (that is,
if we're *past* $x_N$ in the sequence),
then $|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|<\epsilon$.

**What you know:** You know that $x_n$ converges to $x$,
or that for every $\epsilon>0$,
there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$.

If we do your case 1: Suppose that $x=0$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.
Then,
since $x_n\to0$,
there exists $N$ such that if $n\geq0$,
then $|x_n-0|=|x_n|<\epsilon^2$.
Therefore,
$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{0}|=|\sqrt{x_n}|=\sqrt{|x_n|}<\sqrt{\epsilon^2}=\epsilon$,
as desired.

Now you have to prove that it works not only for $x=0$,
but for *any* nonnegative $x$.
Hint:
Recall the *conjugate trick*
$$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}},$$
(note that the above only makes sense if one of $a$ or $b$ is nonzero),
and recall that if $A\geq B$ with $A$ $B$ not zero,
then $\frac{1}{A}\leq\frac{1}{B}$.