# If the sequence $(a_n^2)$ converges and $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then $(a_n)$ also converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Proof or counterexample of the following statement:

> If the sequence $(a_n^2)$ converges and $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then
> $(a_n)$ also converges.

This statement seems true, as I can not encounter any counterexample. Also, because $a_n>0$ the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded, but I can't figure out the solution. I hope someone could give a light.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927286/square-root-of-sequence-approaches-square-root-value) is a duplicate. It goes further and shows where $a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true. The positive square root function $+\sqrt{\cdot} : [0, +\infty) \to [0, +\infty)$ is continuous. And since $a_n > 0$ we have $\sqrt{b_n} = a_n$ where $b_n = a_n^2$. So since continuous functions map convergent sequences to convergent sequences, we have that $a_n = \sqrt{b_n}$ converges if $b_n$ converges.

Comment: "continuous functions map convergent sequences to convergent sequences". I'm still not familiar with that result, but your answer could be correct.

Comment: @rachmani9 You can see the result about continuous functions in the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429902/image-of-a-convergent-sequence-under-a-continuous-function-converges

Comment: I could verify now by the convergence definition of $(a_n^2)$ taking $\varepsilon^2$, but the result you showed seems a nice weapon to use too.

Comment: @rachmani9 Yes, this is a pretty convenient technique.  For more and more complicated expressions, you can imagine that it becomes harder and harder "to construct the perfect $\epsilon$" to show convergence. However, if you can recognize the complicated expression as continuous, you can just bypass the need to do such a construction.

Answer (score -1):

Write $a^2:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n^2$ (I'm assuming you already know that every nonnegative number has a square root), so that
$$
a_n-a= \dfrac{a_n^2-a^2}{a_n+a}.
$$
If $a^2>0$, then the denominator is bounded below, so you get convergence of $(a_n)$ to $a$ (I'll leave the details to you).

If $a^2=0$, then by definition of convergence for fixed $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $a_n^2<\varepsilon^2$. Therefore for all $n\geq N$, $(a_n/\varepsilon)^2<1$, and this gives $a_n/\varepsilon<1$. This shows $(a_n)$ converges to 0.